# How do I this in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three columns (id, version, platform) in a table.

I want that when I go to insert a new record in the table, don't let me insert the same version for the same platform. I mean, if I have a row with (1, 10, android) and another with (2,11, iphone), when I go to insert the new version 10 for android don't be allowed, but if I'm going to add the new version 10 for iphone allow me to do it.

I hope you are understood, thanks. (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite unique index on `(platform, version)`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_platform_version ON tbl (platform, version)
```

Comment: I tried that but it will not let me add only one record per platform. and should be multiple records per platform, but without repeating versions of the same platform.

Comment: Then perhaps you're doing something else incorrectly? Can you post your database schema as well as the code you're using to do inserts?